# Google Sheets Countif with Arrrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, countif

I'm doing some dynamic Monte Carlo simulation in Google Sheets, by utilizing the COUNTIF formula for the simulation. Something is not working the way I thought it would, but I cannot put my finger on. I have two columns that I'm comparing, and I need to count the instances where the value in one column is bigger than the value in the other column. If I do this explicitly by propagating the if comparison formula I obtain the correct result. However, if I do it with

```
=countif( A4:A, ">" & B4:B )
```

I do not obtain the correct result. My [example is at this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MAmrIOszW6s8R7VGFxiMeWgI3MWoCbvXjFEjr18XJ6U/edit#gid=0), the number in cell C4 is the malfunctioning COUNTIF, which equals 2 in the example, and the number in cell E4 is 5, which is the correct count by propagating the comparison in column F and adding the correct comparisons in E4.

```
p1  p2  n           
0.5 0.51    10          
Monte Carlo                 
0.50    0.60    2       5   0
0.90    0.50                1
0.60    0.30                1
0.50    0.60                0
0.40    0.30                1
0.40    0.50                0
0.60    0.70                0
0.60    0.30                1
0.70    0.50                1
0.10    0.30                0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two scenarios with countif:

(1) As a non-array formula, `=countif( A4:A, ">" & B4:B )` would give you the same result as `=countif( A4:A, ">" & B4 )`  i.e. it would count only values of A greater than .60, giving the answer 2.

(2) As an array formula, `=sum(countif( A4:A, ">" & B4:B ))` would give you a separate result for each value of B (2+5+9+2...) giving the answer 56.

If you wanted to use countif, you would need to do something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(A4:A-B4:B,">"&0))
```

Comment: Thank you! The last line is the correction I was looking for. The, ">"&0 can also be brought entirely inside the brackets, as  ">0".

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(A4:A>B4:B, 1)))
```

[image: 0]